# Load variables to model workspace in simulink from file from command

Tags: matlab, simulink

Is there anyway that i can load variables to model workspace in simulink from MAT-file from Matlab command line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the examples at [Model Workspaces](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/using-model-workspaces.html), and particularly [Use MATLAB Commands to Change Workspace Data](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/using-model-workspaces.html#f4-140177).